# Angular 8 how to open angular application by default in crome instead of edge

Tags: angular

ng serve -o

When I am running above command by default my angular application is open in edge browser 
is there any parameter we need to use to open application in google crome by default

Comment: As far as I remember, it opens in your default browser.

Comment: Is there any way to pass pass any specific browser as a parameter

Comment: change your default browser or try debugger for chrome extension if you are using vs code.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking for is not implemented as far as I can tell. It's currently marked as "nice to have" and is out of scope. See [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5508).

Answer (score 0):

You should change your default browser to chrome.